# Chrome mobile all children of body overscroll-behavior bug

Tags: javascript, css, cordova, google-chrome, mobile

So with the release of chrome 63 we get the new `overscroll-behavior` property. In the past we used `overflow:hidden` to get our way but this new property makes a bug with scrolling on mobile more noticeable.

If you go to googles own demo [here](https://ebidel.github.io/demos/chatbox.html) with chrome on Android you can see the bug.

In the chat box if you scroll down and try to scroll back up with out lifting your finger from the screen you will see that you can not unless you scroll up then down. same if you were to scroll all the way up then lift your finger and then try to scroll up then down with out lifting your finger it will get stuck. This happens with ALL children regardless whether overscroll-behavior is used. and is not just limited to the y-axis it happens on x too.

As you can tell this is very annoying to the user.

The only solution that I can think of(not implemented yet) is to listen on scrolling events and when the user scrolls the element all the way to the bottom adjust the scroll by 0.1px this way the user can never truly get to the bottom of a element but this would be very expensive and we know that scroll events aren't always fired right away on mobile causing a snapping effect(and I don't know what other effects it would cause like breaking the users scrolling motion as if they had just lifted their finger).

Also from googles defention of `contain`

> contain - prevents scroll chaining. Scrolls do not propagate to
>   ancestors ***but local effects within the node are shown. For example,
>   the overscroll glow effect on Android*** or the rubberbanding effect on
>   iOS which notifies the user when they've hit a scroll boundary. Note:
>   using overscroll-behavior: contain on the html element prevents
>   overscroll navigation actions.

This does not happen at all thus the spec is broken.

As far as I can tell this happens on all versions of chrome for mobile and it doesn't matter whether it's the webview, website, or full screen add to homepage.

If anyone knows if there is a workaround with out having to completely change the structure of ones app that would be great also if there's a bug tracker for this.

Update:
Bug is being worked on [here](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=798543)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Chrome 65 has fixed this issue.

Answer (score 0):

So this is the workaround I used it works but the user will see a small jump but it's a trade off I can live with.

```
document.querySelector("#somediv").addEventListener("touchstart", function() {

        var clientHeight = this.clientHeight;
        var scrollHeight = this.scrollHeight;
        var scrollTop = this.scrollTop;
        var scroll = scrollHeight - scrollTop;
        var scrollTo;

        if( scroll == clientHeight ) scrollTo = scrollTop - 1;
        if( scroll == scrollHeight ) scrollTo = scrollTop + 1;

        if(scrollTo) return this.scrollTop = scrollTo;

    });
```